# Django: Double-Escape XML Entities

Tags: xml, django, escaping

Running into a bit of a corner case: the API I'm communicating with blows up when there's an ampersand or similar in the data, even though Django is escaping the data when rendering the XML template. The response I get from the API owner was:

```
As weird as it sounds, I think you need to double escape it. Try: &amp;amp;
```

Sensibly, Django doesn't really make this easy. Trying `|escape|escape` doesn't do what I want regardless of whether `autoescape` is on or off. I'm sure I can write a custom filter to do this, but I'm worried that will lead to other issues. Is there a simple way to do this with standard template filters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Django force_escape filter should work if applied twice.

Comment: Nice to see you're still working with Django. Thankfully I figured out what I was doing at some point as well.